# How to connect to server with dynamic IP address over VPN

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, ethernet

I have a server set up with a static IP address over a wired interface (`eno1`). I can ssh into the server remotely through the static IP, but the connection is poor, possibly due to incompatibility with the e1000e driver for the ethernet.

I'm interested in fixing this, but I don't want to do anything that may kill the ethernet connection, since I won't be able to ssh back into the server and I won't have physical access to the machine for another month.

I've been trying to do is ssh into the server over the wireless interface (`wlp6s0`), which has a dynamic IP. I have a VPN for the local network, so I should be able to connect through it, but I haven't been able to.

From the server, I can connect to it to itself with `ssh 10.127.122.42`, but I can't do this from another device running the VPN, although I was able to about a year ago. Any ideas?

`$ ifconfig 
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:32:e4:bb:45:ad

          inet addr:xxx.xxx.10.15  Bcast:xxx.xxx.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/xx Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2987 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:315848 (315.8 KB)  TX bytes:572046 (572.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb100000-fb120000`

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2441664 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:2441664 (2.4 MB)

wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:a5:89:16:fe:71
          inet addr:10.127.122.42  Bcast:10.127.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f3a:72ca:9267:49a1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1506 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:4431
          TX packets:1431 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:460746 (460.7 KB)  TX bytes:139741 (139.7 KB)
          Interrupt:19

Answer (score 0):

I'm no guru at this, but it appears your two ip addresses for wifi and eth are in different ranges so would need a router for an external pc to talk to it if connected on the same network - also your subnet on the wifi card probably should be 255.255.255.0 which could also be stopping the connection.

Have you tried putting the Wireless card on the same network as the ethernet?

--
This link may help you.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115893/how-to-enable-two-network-interfaces-both-for-internet-in-ubuntu12-04

Comment: I tried changing the subnet mask, but still can't connect. What do you mean exactly by having the wireless on the same network as the ethernet?

Comment: Try setting your wifi card to an available static ip address in the same range as your eth0 card above that ends in 10.xx and when you try it make sure the subnet is 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0):

Not that safe but you can use [Dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com/) , it is kind of TeamViewer but with ssh connection to your terminal. As long as your device connected to internet you will be able to find it in dataplicitys portal.